# Using (::) in a class's member function definition

Tags: c++, oop, class, function

I was testing out classes and I made this class

```
class Point
{
private:
    int x,y;
public:
    void setit(int new_x,int new_y);
    void set_x(int new_x);
    void set_y(int new_y);
    int get_x();
    int get_y();
};
```

now I went ahead and wrote the function definitions for all the public functions but,

There is something that puzzled me when i was writing the `void set(int new_x,int new_y);`
function definition

```
void Point::setit(int new_x, int new_y){
    Point::set_x(new_x);
    Point::set_y(new_y);
}

void Point::setit(int new_x, int new_y){
    set_x(new_x);
    set_y(new_y);
}
```

I noticed that the two previous function definitions have the exact same effect.

I thought that without the :: operator it wouldn't work because it would search for the functions outside the class, since I no longer signify they are in the Point class

Can anyone explain why they both have the same effect??

Thank You.

Comment: Can you explain why you thought they'd behave differently?

Comment: @Johnsyweb I thought that without the :: operator it wouldn't work because it would search for these functions outside the class, since I no longer signify they are in the Point class

Comment: Short answer: The body of a class member function definition is part of the *scope* of the class.

Comment: Basically it won't search outside the class for this function because (to put it leman's terms) the functions inside the class are the 'closest'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`::` is the scope resolution operator; it can tell the compiler exactly where to look for a name.

The `Point::set_x` is simply an extended syntax for calling a member function.

```
set_x(new_x);
```

Is short for

```
this->set_x(new_x);
```

And

```
Point::set_x(new_x);
```

Is equivalent for

```
this->Point::set_x(new_x);
```

It allows you to select which function to call when a class hides a function in a parent class. For instance:

```
struct A {
    void f();
};

struct B : public A {
    void f(); // Hides A::f
};

B binst;

binst.f(); // Calls B::f

binst.A::f(); // Calls A::f
```

One thing you can do with this syntax is call the member function of a parent class from the overridden virtual function of a base class, allowing you to use the "default implementation" provided by the base class. You can also do it from outside the class, similar to hidden functions:

```
struct A {
    virtual void f() {
        cout << "A::f" << endl;
    }
};

struct B : public A {
    virtual void f() override {
        cout << "B::f" << endl;

        A::f(); // if we just did f(), it would call B::f, and we
                // would get infinite recursion
    }
};

B b;

b.f();    // prints B::f A::f
b.A::f(); // prints B::f
```

Comment: I apreciate the effort, but this is too advanced for me, Im still learning classes. I didnt learn structs or ->

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil: Well... you asked, no? :)

Comment: @EdS. I did but I just want a simpler answer please :)

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil there is no simpler answer that doesn't sacrifice completeness or truth.

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil A struct and a class are very much the same (you'll learn the only difference between them in the future). `a->b` is like `a.b` but you use the former when `a` is a pointer to an object and the latter when `a` is the object itself.

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil: `a->b` is the same as `(*a).b`, generally.

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil it's just a syntactic shortcut so that when you have a pointer that you want to access a member from, you can do `ptr->member` isntead of the longer `(*pointer).member`

Answer (score 2):

Inside a class member function, all the class member names are in scope, so `set_x` is found.

Moreover, the class name itself is visible inside class member functions (it is said to be *injected*), and thus `Point::set_x` is also found. But for the same reason, `Point::Point::set_x` and `Point::Point::Point::Point::set_x` are also ways to name the function.

Comment: Im probably gonna take what im gonna say now to another question but assume this: I have a function that's outside the class called printnumber. If i call printnumber() inside the function setit() that belongs to the class Point. Will it work or will it assume that printnumber() belongs to Point

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil: Everything in the global namespace is also in scope, everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`::` is a scope resolution operator. To access the function in the scope of the `Point` class' namespace you can use the `::` operator, but because the function `setit(int new_x, int new_y)` is already in the same scope as `set_x` and `set_y`, there is no requirement to define the overall scope of those functions. The program will call the functions with matching symbols to `set_x` and `set_y` in the most local scope.